# Synergy Mac OS X Lion => Windows 7 - modifier keys broken

Tags: osx-lion, synergy

When using Synergy 1.3.7 or 1.4.4 beta on Mac OS X Lion as server, and Windows 7 as client, I can move the mouse onto my Windows computer, but as soon as I press Ctrl, Shift, Command, or Option, the keys start acting like ALT is pressed down on the Windows computer. It gets stuck this way until I move my mouse out and back into the screen.

Anyone have a working setup with Lion/Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying 1.4.5 Beta now and still have this modifier keys issue. So I changed the server to a Windows 7 Box and the client to Mac Lion.

Most of the problems are gone now, but, there is no double click on the Mac.

Comment: I got this working with Synergy 1.3.4 on Lion, as the server, and 1.3.7 on Win7. It's okay, a few glitches but usable.